# how to execute launchBrowser method based on test case type

Tags: selenium, testng

I have an API and Web base Test Case in may test class and i need to run test test case base on test case type.

if test case = Web base than execute `openbrowse` method in my base class
If test Case = API than do Not execute `openbrowse` method in my base class

How to implement such scenario in my TestNg.

Comment: why don't you create two separate class ?

Comment: Because I need a single Extended Report for both the test cases

Comment: show your test class and testng.xml